# flask jinja for loop submit value update within loop for buttoning

Tags: for-loop, flask, button, jinja2, submit

I am using jinja template with a for loop and within my for loop I have buttons that are dependent on other features on the page. I want to be able to use the for loop and loop.index, or something, to allow the button values to be distinguished within the for loop.

I have tried to print out the values to the web page successfully, but the values are not retained for form input submit values within the input button.

I have also tried namespace, but it did not help.
I have also tried a macro using below, and it did not help.

```
{% macro incrF(cntsD, key, inc=1) %}
    {% if cntsD.update({key: cntsD[key] + inc}) %} {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

and

```
{% set dummy=incrF(cntsD,'bintype',1) %}
```

Original code below. Is there some way to accomplish this task?

```
{% for display in graphkv['stdbintxt'][graphkv['dvNL'][loop.index0]]['all']  %}
<br>
<br>DEBUG: loop={{ loop.index0 }} , dvtype={{ cntsD['dvtype'] }} , bintype={{ loop.index0 }}<br>
{{ display }}
<input type="hidden" form="formDV" name="bintype" value="{{ loop.index0 }}">    
<input type="submit" form="formDV" name="dvgotowardbeginning" value= "<" >
<input type="submit" form="formDV" name="dvgotowardend" value= ">" >
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I was not getting the loop info returned correctly

```
requestargsgetkv=request.args.to_dict(flat=True)
```

debug showed:

```
requestargsgetkv= {'dvtype': '0', 'browserid': '1', 'bintype': '0', 'dvgotowardend': '>'}
```

when clicking on what should have been #3, but the raw request showed I was actually getting too much data since only the last kv item (dict) shows up, in my case I was hoping for bintype=3
`<Request 'https://127.0.0.1:5007/graphdata?dvtype=0&browserid=1&bintype=0&bintype=1&bintype=2&bintype=3&bintype=4&dvgotowardend=%3E&bintype=5&dvtype=1&browserid=1' [GET]>`

my problem was two loops, but the form was for both loops.
I added

```
{% set loop1 = loop.index0 %}
```

and

```
{% set loop2 = loop.index0 %}
```

to the correct areas of the loops and changed my form to
id="formDV{{ loop1 }}{{ loop2 }}"
and the request that made it to my route was then correct.  I ended up not using the macros.  I need to always look first at the raw request when something is not expected.